# How to set port for Heroku on a Node.Js Typescript Project

Tags: node.js, typescript, heroku

Normally, Heroku dynamically sets the port for us.

`const PORT : string|number = process.env.PORT || 5000;`

But how do I modify this code to accept PORT... and it's using the => shorthand with Typescript.

```
server.listen(port => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Here's the top of the server class...

```
import express, { Application } from "express";
import socketIO, { Server as SocketIOServer } from "socket.io";
import { createServer, Server as HTTPServer } from "http";
import path from "path";

export class Server {
  private httpServer: HTTPServer;
  private app: Application;
  private io: SocketIOServer;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the app module in http.createserver then only the express can carry over the application through the port

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8888;

http.createServer(app).listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(PORT);
})
```